# Scala List match last element

Tags: scala, pattern-matching

I'm currently learning Scala and I'm amazed. The language handles so much problems quite elegant. But, I got a problem when it comes to matching the last element of a list.

Let's have a look at this code:

```
def stringify(list: List[String]): String = list match {
  case x :: xs => x + (if (xs.length != 0) ":" else "") + stringify(xs)
  case Nil => ""
}
```

This is quite inelegant and I would like to write it more intuitive, something like this:

```
def stringify(list: List[String]): String = list match {
  case x :: xs => x + ":" + stringify(xs)
  case x :: Nil => x
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: @enzyme This is what I went for in my program. I dislike duplicated code.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to switch the order. The `xs` symbol will eagerly match anything in that position. Trying to match `Nil` first will make that statement no longer unreachable. Also, you'll still need to match `Nil` by itself to account for empty lists.

```
def stringify(list: List[String]): String = list match {
   case x :: Nil => x
   case x :: xs => x + ":" + stringify(xs)  
   case Nil => ""
}
```

Though `mkString` already does what you're looking to make.

Comment: This is a good answer to the question. Just note to the op that be careful with the recursion. If you can aim to right your methods as tail recursive as this will allow the compiler to optimise the implementation by reusing the stack so it will scale for larger data sets. http://oldfashionedsoftware.com/2008/09/27/tail-recursion-basics-in-scala/

Comment: @LionelPort My aim is always to produce tail recursion for the named optimizations. That is the reason why I love functional programming.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an implementation using `List#foldRight`:

```
 def stringify(list: List[String]): String = 
         list.foldRight(""){ 
               (e, acc) => if (acc.isEmpty) e 
                           else { e + ":" + acc } 
         }
```

When folding over this list, we need to check for when the accumulator is empty. Otherwise, we'll get an extra `:` at the end of the `stringfied` string result.

**Tests**

```
scala> stringify(List("1", "2" , "3") )
res6: String = 1:2:3

scala> stringify(List("1", "2" , "3", "500") )
res7: String = 1:2:3:500
```

Comment: Wow, this is another nice approach! Thanks for the inspiration.